# vim: using a regular key as a modifier

Tags: vim

I would like to use `<Space>` as a modifier, just like `Ctrl`, `Alt` or `Shift`.

For example, the `hjkl` keys could jump 10 times instead of just one when Space is pressed.  Something like:

```
nnoremap <Space-h> 10h
nnoremap <Space-j> 10j
nnoremap <Space-k> 10k
nnoremap <Space-l> 10l
```

This almost works:

```
nnoremap <Space>j 10j
```

but I need to release the `<Space>` and press it again to repeat the custom movement.

Comment: You mean that in emacs it's easy.  Is it even possible in Vim?  Maybe in Linux itself? (Somebody did it for Windows+AutoHotKey)

Comment: I was really just making a joke, but it's a lot rarer for vim to use simultaneous key combinations to do something and instead use its modes.  `emacs` on the other hand uses simultaneous keys a lot more (not sure, I'm a `vim` user).  Maybe this will help you, though: https://github.com/vim-scripts/arpeggio

Comment: Close, but not quite.  I just tested it, and it works the first time you press the combination, but not the following ones, unless you release both keys and press them both again.  I am looking for something like: `<press Space>jjjjj<release Space>` to move down 50 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[arpeggio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425) is a Vim plugin that lets you  define keymappings of simultaneous keys to other keys, e.g. `j` and `k` at the same time to have the same effect as `<Esc>`.

Comment: Close, but not quite. I just tested it, and it works the first time you press the combination, but not the following ones, unless you release both keys and press them both again. I am looking for something like: <press Space>jjjjj<release Space> to move down 50 lines.

Comment: No, you do `50j` to move down 50 lines.

Answer (score 1):

`<Space>` is not a modifier key and you can't fool Vim into thinking that it is. Unless you do something system-wise, like swapping `Ctrl` and `Space`.

Look around for a keybinding solution for your OS.